# Speed up VBA code on extracting relevant rows to new worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I need to copy relevant rows to a new Excel worksheet. The code will loop through each row in the original worksheet and select rows based on relevant countries and products specified in the array into the second worksheet.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

a = Worksheets("worksheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
Dim countryArray(1 To 17) As Variant
Dim productArray(1 To 17) As Variant

' countryArray(1)= "Australia" and so on...
' productArray(1)= "Product A" and so on...

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
For i = 3 To a
    For Each j In countryArray
        For Each k In productArray
        Sheets("worksheet1").Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets("worksheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        Next
    Next
Next

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```

Each time I ran the code, the spreadsheet stopped responding in a matter of minutes. Would appreciate if someone could help me on this, thanks in advance!

Comment: You want Application.ScreenUpdating = True at the end to switch back on repaint.

Comment: I would also add `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` and `Application.EnableEvents = False` to speed up things. Do not forget to reverse it at the end of your code.

Comment: //define countryArray and productArray is not how you comment in VBA. Use '

Comment: There are no values in **countryArray** or **productArray**, so why loop over them??

Comment: Code is strange anyway because he loops over countryArray and productArray but never uses them. So the loop is more or less over the number and that means he copies the same range over and over again. What is that good for? Or am I wrong here?

Comment: Depending on information you have not shared, you will speed this up considerably by one of the following: `1` Read the entire table into a VBA array; iterate through the array extracting the relevant *rows* to a Dictionary/Collection; write the results to a `results` array and write that back to the new worksheet. `2` Use a Filter and use the `.SpecialCells(xlvisible)` property to copy to the new worksheet. `3` Use the Advanced Filter which allows the copy in one action; but requires writing a `Criteria Array` to the worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some pointers:

1. Remember to declare all your variables and use `Option Explicit` at the top of your code
2. Use `With` statements to ensure working with right sheet and not implicit activesheet or you may end up with wrong end row count
3. Only `i` contributes to the loop so you are making unnecessary loop work
4. Gather qualifying ranges with `Union` and copy in one go
5. Remember to switch back on `screen-updating`

Code:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim unionRng As Range, a As Long, i As Long
    With Worksheets("worksheet1")
        a = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

        For i = 3 To a
            If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then
                Set unionRng = Union(unionRng, .Cells(i, 1))
            Else
                Set unionRng = .Cells(i, 1)
            End If
        Next

        With Worksheets("worksheet2")
            unionRng.EntireRow.Copy .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row +1
        End With
    End With

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: As an aside, `Application.ScreenUpdating` will be automatically changed to `True` when the macro exits.  I, too, reset it explicitly in my code, as I think it lends clarity and avoids confusion, but it is not strictly required.

Comment: Did this help at all?

Comment: I think the OP will only get notified if you post the comment to the question

Comment: Many thanks @RonRosenfeld . Sorry to have disturbed.

Comment: No disturbance. Sitting here doing other stuff and taking a break.